# Mysql performance for large query using for value in VS multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I was optimizing mysql queries for a project, and replaced many situations were a small query was run inside a loop thousands of times with a single query using For value IN() and i got a significant speed boost.

However, for some queries where the row id list got bigger, the performance of Value IN () got much worse, and it actually takes much longer to perform one query vs thousands of smaller ones.

All the queries are using indexes.
How / why is it faster to run a query 20 000 times compared to making one query with a value list containing 20 000 items. In the end, I would expect mysql do the same lookup of 20 000 rows, just without the overhead of sending the request - downloading the response every loop cycle.
Expecting the Value IN be faster feels intuitive yet it isnt.
Is there something I can optimize/configure in the query/database side ?

For context: Im optimizing queries compiled by Laravel framework. Previous devs didnt notice that the framework made "n" queries every time a property was accessed. I used eager loading to make single queries, but it made some queries run much slower( which is odd )

---

An example of a query that got slower. Running below query tens of thousands of times

```
select * from `products` 
where `products`.`id` = ? 
and `products`.`deleted_at` is null 
limit 1
```

is faster than running the next query once:

```
select * from `products` 
where `products`.`id` 
IN ([list of 20 000 ids]) 
and `products`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: Can you characterize the queries that got slower? Are they using a lot of JOINs? Can you post example(s) of queries that were affected?

Comment: Updated with an example query.